# Does this notion of "weak" isomorphism exist in literature?

Tags: reference-request, equivalence-relations, binary-operations, magma

Let $(M,\circ)$ and $(N,\ast)$ be two magmas.
I'd like to relax the notion of isomorphism by defining a notion of "weak" isomorphism in the following way:
$M$ and $N$ are "weakly" isomorphic if there exist two bijections $\eta,\xi:M\longrightarrow N$ such that
\begin{equation}
\forall\ x,y\in M,\qquad \eta(x\circ y)=\xi(x)\ast\xi(y)
\end{equation}
With this definition the magma $(M,\circ)$ defined by taking $M=\{x,y\}$ and setting $x\circ x:=y$, $x\circ y=y\circ x= y\circ y := x$ and the magma $(N,\ast)$ defined by taking $N=\{a,b\}$ and setting $b\circ b:=a$, $a\circ b=b\circ a= a\circ a := b$ are "weakly" isomorphic but not isomorphic.

My question is, is this notion existing and/or used in literature? If yes, could you please point me towards some references?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be interested in the definition of [**isotopy**](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Isotopy_of_magmas) ([**homotopy**](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Homotopy_of_magmas)) of magmas.

Also: [**Isotope Of A Groupoid** on planetmath.org](http://planetmath.org/IsotopeOfAGroupoid).

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I was searching for.